# jQuery Mobile page overrides desktop HTML div layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'd like to use jQuery mobile on my desktop page.
I'm probably thinking of this wrongly, but I tried simply inserting a page element into an existing standard div, like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="left_sidebar"> [...] </div>

    <div id="mylist" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="listview"> [list items bla bla] </div>
    </div>

    <div id="right_sidebar"> [...] </div>
    <div id="site_footer"> (c) bla blub </div>
</body>
```

...hoping that only the middle part displays the "mobile" page elements.

However, that page div seems to override the entire site, making all the other divs invisible, and turns the whole body into a mobile page (albeit displaying my listview item nicely... across the entire screen).

Any idea what to do?

Advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should never include jQuery Mobile hoping it will only style part of your page. jQuery Mobile is extremely intrusive, it will overtake your whole page..

You have 2 possible solutions for your problem. Force jQuery Mobile to skip some of your content, **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/how-to-remove-jquery-mobile-styling/)** you can find available solutions.

On the other hand, if you need only some jQuery Mobile functionality you should rebuild framework using only needed things, you can do it **[here](http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/)**.

Comment: I see, but that seems a lot more complicated. My only worry with iframes is that I can't use them for too many items, say lots of jquery mobile buttons etc... that's a lot of iframes.

Comment: Sorry but your solution looks like killing a mosquito with atomic bomb. There's no point in using iFrames when there are other appropriate solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I seem to have found one way (I don't know if there is another), which is to simply keep the mobile page separate and call it into an iframe.

Trivial almost, but I would have hoped that there is a way to do this with simple div layouts.

Anyway, so this is what I ended up with:

```
<body>
    <div id="left_sidebar"> [...] </div>

   <iframe src="JQMPage.html" frameborder="0" width="490" onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);'></iframe>

    <div id="right_sidebar"> [...] </div>
    <div id="site_footer"> (c) bla blub </div>
</body>
```

...in which "JQMPage.html" is my separately saved mobile page and the resizeIframe function just resizes the iframe's height based on the "JQMPage.html" page's height, to extend as the list extends.

Any better ideas are welcome though!
Cheers

Comment: Don't do it like this, look at my answer below.

Comment: I'll definitely have a look at that jQuery Mobile Download Builder. If I understand correctly, I could take only the individual elements I want to use, without those that would override the entire page?

Comment: Actually I just found that if you take away the page initiation/formatting, a large portion of the widgets and other features are automatically disabled as well...  So I'll look at your other option to skip elements by force.